# R: How to select 100 random rows based on column text?

Tags: r

I'm using the spam dataset in R where one of the columns ("type") divides e-mails into "spam" and "nonspam"

I want to create an object with 100 randomly selected rows that are classed as "spam".

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I think it's a bit unfair you get downvoted as you are obviously new to the site. I agree though that the question could be improved. Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use :

```
spam[sample(which(spam$type == 'spam'), 100), ]
```

add `replace = TRUE` if you do not have sufficient rows for `type = "spam"`.

---

To make sure that rows are not repeated for test and train, we can do

```
inds <- which(spam$type == 'spam')
train <- sample(inds, 100)
test <- sample(setdiff(inds, train), 100)
```

Then subset the indices from the main dataframe

```
train.data <- spam[train, ]
test.data <- spam[test, ]
```

Comment: Thanks, what if I want to ensure that the same sample is not taken twice for test and train data (i.e. duplicate samples under 2 different sample selections)? Does replace = FALSE solve the issue?

Answer (score 2):

```
library(kernlab)
data(spam)
```

In `base`

```
set.seed(12345)
smpl_spam <- spam[sample(which(spam$type == "spam"), 100), ]
```

In `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(12345)
smpl_spam <- spam %>% 
  filter(type == "spam") %>% 
  sample_n(100)
```